# Visual Studio Entity Data Model Designer на mac os x

Tags: asp.net-mvc

Друзья, установил visual studio на mac, создал пустой веб-проект с mvc, подключил через NuGet необходимые зависимости для работы с Entity Framework.

Никак не могу найти, каким образом запустить визуальный реактор сущностей (хотел сначала набросать классов и потом уже пульнуть их в базу).

Помогите разобраться, пожалуйста!

Comment: Метка asp.net-mvc каким боком здесь?

Comment: Добавьте метки используемого языка программирования и укажите точную версию EF.

Comment: Если используете EF Core, то для него нет подхода Model First. Но, вроде, есть сторонние утилиты визуальные дизайнеры.